# Alfresco folder rule to create publicly sharable link for the children

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I am using Enterprise Alfresco.

I want to have a rule on my folder that will create a publicly shareable link whenever a new document created in the folder. The sharable should be the same as what we can create using the share ui.

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can Refer logic of publicly shareable code in below webscript.

ShareContentPost.java

QuickShareService.java